# TypeConverters on the compact framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, properties, typeconverter

I'm working on a compact framework project and whilst most of the properties are fairly straight forward (I.e. mark them as browsable in the xmta file), I'm struggling to get this to work for more complex types - on the full framework, I'd just implement a custom `TypeConverter` and go from there, but it seems the CF `TypeConverter` doesn't have any of the type converting methods to override, which has left me a little stuck?

It probably should be blindingly obvious but how would I go about supporting design time property support for more complex type?

Comment: Could you describe, in more detail, what it is you want to accomplish?

Comment: I was initially going to start trivial, with something that allows spherical co-ordinates to be stored and edited in the properties window, in a similar manner to how the `Point` class does it